# List files larger than {size} sorted by date

Tags: find, ls

I want to solve the problem 'list the top 10 most recent files in the current directory over 20MB'.

With `ls` I can do:

```
ls -Shal |head
```

to get top 10 largest files, and:

```
ls -halt |head
```

to get top 10 most recent files

With find I can do:

```
find . -size +20M
```

To list all files over 20MB in the current directory (and subdirectories, which I don't want).

Is there any way to list the top ten most recent files over a certain size, preferably using `ls`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The 'current directory' option for `find` is `-maxdepth 1`. The whole commandline for your needs is:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +20M -print0 | xargs -0 ls -Shal | head
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +20M -print0 | xargs -0 ls -halt | head
```

Comment: This sorts the files in blocks of a couple of thousand, apparently as many as fit on a command line. See  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149615 (plus https://stackoverflow.com/a/32293551 on a Mac) for avoiding that.

Answer (score 8):

Note: This will work for GNU-find, but not every other find.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -size +20M -printf "%T@ %f\n" | 
    sort -nr | head -n 20 | sed 's/[^ ]\+ //'
```

Starting like @Rajish, but using the `printf` command from `find` to specify the output format. There are 3 time-related formats, *atime, ctime* and *mtime* - `%T` is for mtime, `%A` and `%C` are for the other formats.

`@` is to specify the timeformat in seconds since epoch. `%f` is for the filename, `\n` for a newline between 2 files.

Then sorting by number in reversed order gives the youngest files first, and we take 20 lines¹ with `head`.

In the end, `sed` is used, to throw away the time information.

¹) since `head` works line by line, a single file with more than 20 newlines in the name, which is a bit unusual, but not prohibited, can corrupt the output if it is belong the first 20 matches. If you happen to have such files, please try to get rid of them - well, to change their name. They will often be a problem for simple scripts.

Comment: If you use `file`'s `-ls` command, the special characters will be printed as backslash-escaped characters: `find . -maxdepth 1 -size +20M -printf "%T@ " -ls | sort -nr | head -n 20 | sed 's/[^ ]\+ //'`. Additionally the format will look like `ls -l`, EoghanM also specified `-l` anyway.

Comment: `printf` only works for specific GNU distributions.

Comment: `%T+` generates human readable timestamps like`2018-11-06+13:37:54.4606466460` which are also sortable by `sort` (without `-n`), see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29899/how-can-i-use-find-and-sort-the-results-by-mtime/29901#29901

Answer (score 6):

Zsh's [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) make this easy. The `.` qualifier selects only regular files, `Lm+20` selects files that are at least 20MB plus one byte long; to include files that are exactly 20MB long, use `L+20971519`. Then `om` sorts by decreasing modification time, and `[1,10]` restricts the expansion to the first 10 matches. You still need the `-t` option to `ls` if you want to list the files by date; or you can pass the files to some other command (youngest first). To pass the files to another command with the oldest file first, use `Om` to sort by increasing modification time and `[-10,-1]` to extract the last 10 matches.

```
ls -ltr -- *(.Lm+20om[1,10])
echo *(.Lm+20Om[-10,-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a better way to solve the problem...

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +20M -exec ls -Shal {} \+ | head
```

To get rid of any errors while find tries to access files that you don't have permission to read you might want to add

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +20M -exec ls -Shal {} \+ 2> /dev/null | head
```

Answer (score 1):

This will print only the specified 10 files, regardless of any embedded newline chars in file names. It uses file system `inodes`

```
cd "$1"
for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +20M -printf "%T@\t%i\n" \ 
           | sort -nr | head | cut -f 2)
do
  ls -l "$(find . -inum $i)"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the answers. What I've gone for is the following:

```
ls -halt | grep "M " |head
```

Although it forgoes the 20 Megabytes in favour of anything over a megabyte (and under a gigabyte), it's easy to remember and preserves the human readable element of the filesizes.

Comment: You should *not* attempt to parse the output of `ls`, it shows you a representation of files, nothing more. For simple file names, the output mostly happens to be equivalent to the file name, but you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: That's true I'm sure, but in terms of a human user (and output not being piped elsewhere), this one is easier to remember as it can be put together easier from known simple tools http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/c1089.htm