# How can I use `find` and sort the results by mtime?

Tags: find, ls

I want to use `find` but sort the results reverse chronologically as with `ls -ltr`. Is this possible through any combo of flags or pipelines?

Comment: Best way is 'find <yadda yada> -exec ls -ltr {} +'.

Comment: @gaoithe That works only up to a certain number of files. Beyond that, the files will be split in batches.

Comment: Voting to reopen because https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20611/list-files-larger-than-size-sorted-by-date wants only in current directory "and subdirectories, which I don't want".

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a duplicate at all.  Even the answers of the two questions are distinct.

Comment: To find **all files on disk** sorted by date, I use `sudo find / -printf "%T+ %p\n" | grep -v "/proc/" | grep -v "/sys/" | sort | less +G`    (I remove `proc` and `sys` on purpose here).

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Use `find`'s `-printf` command to output both the time (in a sortable way) and the file, then sort. If you use GNU find,

```
find . your-options -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort
```

For convenience here is an explanation of the `-printf "%T+ %p\n"` from `man find`:

- `%Tk` File's last modification time in the format specified by `k`, which is the same as for `%A`.

  - where `k` in this case is set to `+`
  - `+`      Date and time, separated by `+`, for example `2004-04-28+22:22:05.0'.  This is a GNU extension.  The time is given in the current  timezone  (which may be affected by setting the TZ environment variable).  The seconds field includes a fractional part.
- `%p`     File's name.

Comment: `sort -r` for reverse order.

Comment: `ls -t` sorts newer to older, `sort` sorts older to newer. So `ls -t`'s reverse order is `sort`'s normal order.

Comment: Do you have a version for OS X (non-gnu)?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni No, sorry. Looking at the [man page](http://ss64.com/osx/find.html) I'd say it would entail using the `-ls` argument and then `cut` (or `awk`) to extract the desired fields.... but better ask a new question about it, and somebody will come up with a complete answer.

Comment: This does not work if you're using `-or ` to combine multiple iname options in find. The -printf only prints the results of the last ORed condition. Any thoughts on how to work around that?

Comment: For OS X and non-GNU, use [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/546900/365890).

Comment: @SSilk Group your expression: `find . your-options \( your-expression \) -printf "..." | sort`.

Comment: Dont work in non-GNU or other distributions... -1

Comment: To get this to work with OSX, install findutils from homebrew, then use gfind not find.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752818/find-lacks-the-option-printf-now-what

Comment: @TomHale didn't work on my 10.12.6: find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Comment: suspicious result: `1985-10-26+09:15:00.0000000000 app/react/node_modules/abab/CHANGELOG.md` (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git)

Comment: And to get the filename of the lastest file: `find YOUR-OPTIONS -printf '%T+\t%p\n' |sort -r |head -1 |cut -s -f2`

Answer (score 5):

If that is just a depth-n (assume depth-2) folder hierarchy, I find this one useful:

```
ls -laht --full-time */*
```

Comment: This seems to produce a list of files that are exactly two folders deep (no more, no less), along with separate listings of each of the folders that are exactly two folders deep.

Comment: @mwfearnley that is exactly what I meant by "that is just a depth-n" above :) you can do `*/*/*` if you want depth 3

Comment: So basically, your suggestion only works as intended when all the files are exactly n levels deep, and there are no subfolders at that level.  You should explain that.  The latter might be surmountable by another flag for `ls`, and you can perhaps cover all levels up to `n` with `ls ... * */* */*/* ...`

Comment: May not work: `bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long`