# Sorting ls output by time, when there are too many files for a single invocation

Tags: shell, ls

I know that I can sort the output of `ls` by time with the `-t` option.

I know that when I have so many files that they don't fit in a single `ls` invocation, I can normally use `xargs` (or `find ... -exec ... {} +`) to let `ls` be called multiple times.

How can I combine the two? I have more files than fit on the command-line, and wish to list them sorted by time. `find . -type f -exec ls -t {} +` doesn't work, because supposing exactly 1000 file names fit on the command-line, and 3000 files are present, this will run `ls -t [first 1000 files]; ls -t [second 1000 files]; ls -t [last 1000 files]`, where the last 1000 files `find` sees may well have a modification time before any of the first 1000. It doesn't seem like anything involving `xargs` or equivalent has any chance whatsoever of working, it seems like that approach is fundamentally flawed, but I cannot find a way that *does* work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`ls -t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) on its own will list all files in the current directory with that sorting, without ever needing to list them on the command line at all.

If you need the recursion behaviour of `find`, or to do some other tests on the files, you can have `find` generate timestamped entries, either through `stat` or through GNU `find`'s `-printf` option and sort it. Something like:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zn
```

[`-printf '%T@ %p\0'`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) generates null-separated Unix timestamp (`%T@`)-filename (`%p`) pairs. [`sort -z`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) is also a non-standard GNU extension, which uses null-delimited records to be filename-safe. The `sort` option is supported in most of the BSDs too, but `-printf` is GNU-only as far as I know.

You can cut that output back into filenames only, or any other format you like.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know `-printf` was this powerful. According to the documentation, `%A@` is the access time. I'm looking for the mtime, so I'd need `%T@`.

Comment: It's once again astonishing what seemingly simple tools have in stock...

Comment: What command would you use to cut each of the NUL delimited strings after the first space?

Comment: @kasperd, (GNU) `sed -z 's/^[^ ]* //'`  or `tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | cut -d ' ' -f2- | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` with `perl` Posixly:

```
$ find ! -name . -prune -print | perl -lne '
    $h{$_} = -M;
    END { print for sort {$h{$a} <=> $h{$b}} keys %h }
'
```

This assume that you don't have newline character in your filename.

To handle newline, you can:

```
$ find ! -name . -prune -exec printf "%s\0" {} + | perl -0lne ...
```

or use `perl -le` then `split /\0/,<>` in your code.

Comment: Oh, nice. Although I don't have newline characters in file names, it can be made to handle them (and still valid for any POSIX find, I think, although the use of perl is inherently somewhat non-portable) by adjusting it to `find ... -exec printf "%s\0" {} + | perl -0lne '...'`, optionally also modifying the perl bit to print newlines instead of NULs, or act on the files directly.

Comment: @hvd: `-printf` is not POSIX. `perl` is more portable, always.

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't use `-printf`. I used `-exec` in combination with POSIX's `printf` utility.

Comment: I was referring to my comment here, where I didn't use `%T@`. `%T@` won't work with the `printf` utility, only with `find`'s non-portable `-printf` option.

Comment: @hvd: If you use that, you acn use `perl -le`, then `split /\0/,<>` to get list of all files.

Comment: Yes, that works too.

Comment: @hvd: Add details in my answer.

Comment: Beware `perl`'s `-M` uses `stat(2)`, not `lstat(2)` so it behaves like `ls -Lt`, not `ls -t`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Good point. I don't think about that. So do you know a perl way to behave like `ls -l`?

Comment: (you mean `ls -t`?). You can use `lstat()` or do `-l; -M _`. Also note that `-M` doesn't support sub-second precision. You can use the `stat` from `Time::HiRes` for that. Note that `lstat` was only very recently added to `Time::HiRes`.

Answer (score 3):

In zsh:

```
print -rl -- *(om)
```

The [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `om` sorts files by modification time (reverse chronological order, i.e. newest first, like `ls -t`). Use `Om` to get the opposite order (chronological order, like `ls -tr`). Make this `*(Dom)` to include dot files.

You can of course vary the [pattern](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators), for example `**/*(Dom)` to recurse into subdirectories. If you want to use multiple patterns, put them in parentheses and use the `|` operator to separate them, e.g. `*.(png|jpg)(om)`.

Since `print` is a shell builtin, this command is not affected by the maximum command line length limit. If you want to call an external command to act on the files in batches and in order, you'll run into the length limit. You can use `printf '%s\0' *(om) | xargs -0 somecommand` to feed the files to xargs if your xargs supports null-separated input (Linux, *BSD), or zsh's own [`zargs`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs):

```
autoload -U zargs
zargs -r -e '' -- *(om) '' somecommand
```

To process one file at a time, use a simple loop, which zsh lets you abbreviate (csh-style):

```
for x (*(om)) somecommand
```

Comment: This ignores the fact that I was searching files in all subdirectories. Does zsh have anything like bash's `globstar` option to address that? A quick search suggests `**/*`, but I don't have zsh installed to verify.

Comment: @hvd, the `**/*` syntax was invented by `zsh` in the early 90s, decades before `bash` copied (a subset of) it. See [The result of ls * , ls ** and ls ***](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665/22565) for more historical details of that globbing operator. zsh 1991, ksh93 2003, fish 2005, bash 2009, tcsh 2010.