# need to move only zip files to separate directory and unzip them

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu, aws

I have a directory **/home/ubuntu/uploads** .  I need to check if it contains any zip file. if it contains then I need to move the oldest modified file according to date to a different directory called **/home/ubuntu/temp**.  Then I need to unzip the zip file we got in  **/home/ubuntu/temp**  to a directory called **/home/ubuntu/s3**.   And at last I need to mark the file as successfully moved.

Here is what I am doing in bash script ->

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z  `ls -t /home/ubuntu/uploads/*.zip | tail -1` ]] ; then
    echo 'No new zip file to move !'
    exit
fi

TIME=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
UPLOADS='/home/ubuntu/uploads'
TEMP='/home/ubuntu/temp'
BUCKET='/home/ubuntu/s3'

FILENAME=`ls -t /home/ubuntu/uploads/*.zip | tail -1 | xargs -n 1 basename `
FILEPATH=`ls -t /home/ubuntu/uploads/*.zip | tail -1`

cp $FILEPATH $TEMP
unzip -u $TEMP/"$FILENAME" -d $BUCKET
rm -rf  $TEMP/*
mv /home/ubuntu/uploads/"$FILENAME"  /home/ubuntu/uploads/"$FILENAME".success.$TIME
```

It kind of works but it is not able to handle zip filenames containing space.

If someone can suggest a better and improved version of this please

Comment: So where does it actually fail?

Comment: I need to know if this can be done easily with just one for loop in a standard form. Also check for bad corrupted zip files and remove them from source directory.

Comment: Can you update your question accordingly with proper statement of what question(s) you really have and what is expected behaviour of script?

Comment: instead of ls better use [find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20611) it can handle [non-trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210472) file names. always use double quotes for file names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked ..thanks everyone !

```
#!/bin/bash

# logs last error
#exec 3>&1 4>&2
#trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
#exec 1>log.out 2>&1

# check for file names with space and rename
for file in /home/ubuntu/uploads/*' '*
do
  if [ -e "${file// /_}" ]
  then
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "Warning, skipping $file as the renamed version already exists"
    continue
  fi

  mv -- "$file" "${file// /_}"
done

# check for zip files
if [[ -z  `ls -t /home/ubuntu/uploads/*.zip | tail -1` ]] ; then
    echo 'No new zip file to move !'
    exit
fi

# check for bad zip file and remove
shopt -s dotglob nullglob globstar
for file in /home/ubuntu/uploads/*.zip; do
    [[ -r $file ]] || continue
    unzip -t "$file" >/dev/null 2>&1 ||  rm -f "$file"
done


TIME=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
UPLOADS='/home/ubuntu/uploads'
TEMP='/home/ubuntu/temp'
BUCKET='/home/ubuntu/s3'

FILENAME=`ls -t /home/ubuntu/uploads/*.zip | tail -1 | xargs -n 1 basename `
FILEPATH=`ls -t /home/ubuntu/uploads/*.zip | tail -1`

cp $FILEPATH $TEMP

unzip -u $TEMP/$FILENAME -d $BUCKET

rm -rf  $TEMP/*

mv /home/ubuntu/uploads/"$FILENAME"  /home/ubuntu/uploads/"$FILENAME".success.$TIME
```